# How to achieve horizontal scrolling effect of Apple's Photos app?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

If you'd go to Photos app's For You section and scroll featured photos you'd see smooth snapping effect for each cell.

I have a horizontally scrollable collection view where I want to have the same effect. So far I've managed to make it somehow similar to what I want by creating custom Collection View Layout by subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout and overriding this method:

```
override func targetContentOffset(
    forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint,
    withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint
  ) -> CGPoint {
    let point = super.targetContentOffset(
      forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset,
      withScrollingVelocity: velocity
    )
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
      return point
    }

    let contentWidth = itemSize.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
    let anchor = collectionView.contentOffset.x / contentWidth
    let currentPage: CGFloat
    if velocity.x == 0 {
      currentPage = round(anchor)
    } else if velocity.x < 0 {
      currentPage = floor(anchor)
    } else {
      currentPage = ceil(anchor)
    }
    let flickVelocity = velocity.x * 0.2
    let flickedPages = (abs(round(flickVelocity)) <= 1) ? 0 : round(flickVelocity)
    let newHorizontalOffset = ((currentPage + flickedPages) * (itemSize.width + minimumInteritemSpacing)) -
      collectionView.contentInset.left

    return CGPoint(x: newHorizontalOffset, y: point.y)
  }
```

But in reality if I scroll a bit harder it will go 2 cells forward or back: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4TDi.jpg

How could I achieve strong yet smooth snapping effect (content offset) for my collection view as in Photos App?

Comment: i think that's because of velocity you assign as next page that's why just change  `let flickVelocity = velocity.x * 10` and check. your side code assign new cell as first as i seen your code. it will scroll to next cell. if you want scrolling like photo app than just remove velocity values from code.

Comment: @jatinfl well, that's not quite right, if I set it to times 10, a small scroll would rapidly make it far to the last cell. The problem is not about velocity as even if I make it million times smaller, it would still go 2 cells right or left if I apply a bit of speed

Comment: you need fast and smooth scrolling like photo app. Right?

Comment: Yeah, smooth with strong snapping position (content offset). If I'd be scrolling from cell 0 it'd go to cell 1 but not 2 despite scrolling force or speed.

Comment: finally found.`let flickedPages = (abs(round(flickVelocity)) <= 1) ? 0 : round(flickVelocity)`use round here like `flickVelocity.rounded(.down)`

Comment: @jatinfl still the same behaviour xD

Comment: please check while hard scrolling the value of `flickedPages` and let me know.

Comment: @jatinfl the value is 0

Comment: than how it scroll ?